# Node.js Express App - Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider TypeError: $(element).slider is not a function

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, node-modules, rickshaw

This is a similar question to [Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider TypeError: $(element).slider is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645833/rickshaw-graph-rangeslider-typeerror-element-slider-is-not-a-function)

The difference is that I'm using Rickshaw in a node.js app using the Express framework.

I'm getting the error: "TypeError: $(element).slider is not a function". (Line 2)

I specified jquery-ui ("^1.10.5") as a dependency in my package.json folder.
Did an "npm install" and see the jquery-ui folder in the node_modules folder.
I'm not sure why it's missing in the context below and then causing the error.

```
$( function() {
$(element).slider( {

    range: true,
    min: graph.dataDomain()[0],
    max: graph.dataDomain()[1],
    values: [ 
        graph.dataDomain()[0],
        graph.dataDomain()[1]
    ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {

        graph.window.xMin = ui.values[0];
        graph.window.xMax = ui.values[1];
        graph.update();

        // if we're at an extreme, stick there
        if (graph.dataDomain()[0] == ui.values[0]) {
            graph.window.xMin = undefined;
        }
        if (graph.dataDomain()[1] == ui.values[1]) {
            graph.window.xMax = undefined;
        }
    }
} );
```

} );

Update:

Perhaps I need to use the Grunt build system?

Building jQuery UI

> jQuery UI uses the Grunt build system.
>
> To build jQuery UI, you must have node.js installed and then run the
>   following commands:
>
> Install the Grunt CLI npm install -g grunt-cli
>
> Clone the jQuery UI git repo git clone git://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui.git cd jquery-ui
>
> Install the node module dependencies npm install
>
> Run the concat task to concatenate files grunt concat
>
> There are many other tasks that can be run through Grunt.
>   For a list of all tasks: grunt --help

Answer (score 1):

Wherever $ or a jquery-ui function was not defined, in rickshaw.js, I included the respective libraries

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
```

or

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');
```

It's a temporary solution, for now...